# Is there an API call for setting the audio in speaker mode in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a button and I'm trying to set the audio to the speaker when the button is clicked. My tries have been futile. Any recommendations?

```
speakerButton.setOnClickListener {

            // Check if the speaker is currently on or off
            val isSpeakerOn = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn

// Toggle the speakerphone state
            audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = !isSpeakerOn

// Update the audio routing
            audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

// Update the speaker button icon based on the speakerphone state
            if (!isSpeakerOn) {
                speakerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_cross_svgrepo_com)
            } else {
                speakerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_volume_up_24)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission
and `audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true` should do the work!

Comment: I have that permission set on the Manifest but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you're working with audioPlayback in your application, double check audio session. audioManager can interact with audio session, so conflicts may happen.